# Reversing algorithm using bitwise OR operator

Tags: c, encryption

I'm working on a problem whereby I am trying to take a string which has been encrypted using a known algorithm and key to it's original plaintext value.

The algorithm uses an XOR operating and bit shifting to encrypt the plaintext.

I have been working on the assumption which appears partially correct, that this process can be reversed by performing a bit shift in the opposite direction and then an XOR operation, as below.

```
WHERE
c = a ^ b
THEN
a = c ^ b
```

The encryption function generates a key via `rand()` which is seeded by a known value, the result of `time(NULL)`. Given the known seed for `rand()` I can regenerate the keys.

This generally works fine and I am able to generate some of the correct characters from the encrypted input. You can see in the screenshot below some of the original string, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO" being decoded correctly.

[image]

The problem I have (I think) is the below line within the encryption function.

```
input[pos] = input[pos] << key | input[pos]  >> 8 - key;
```

My understanding is the bitwise `OR` within C is lossy and cannot be reversed or original inputs recovered. I am slightly stumped on how to overcome this issue without creating a new script to simply brute force each position by encrypting all possible characters and looking for a match.

This is an example of what I am doing with an encryption and decryption function. Note that the encryption function is what comes with the exercise and I don't have the option of modifying it.

How can I overcome this or is it simply not possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void decrypt(int pos);
void encrypt(int pos);

char input[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO";

int main() {

    long input_len = sizeof(input);
    // Hardcoding for consistency when testing
    // int seed = time(NULL);
    int seed = 1663606418;
    srand(seed);

    for(int i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
        encrypt(i);
    }

    printf(input);
    printf("\n\n");

    // Reseeding to get the same order for rand() when decrypting
    srand(seed);
    for(int i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
        decrypt(i);
    }

    printf(input);
}

void encrypt(int pos) {
        int r1 = rand();
        int key = rand() & 7;
        input[pos] = input[pos] ^ r1;
        input[pos] = (input[pos] << key) | (input[pos]  >> 8 - key);
}

void decrypt(int pos) {
        int r1 = rand();
        int key = rand() & 7;
        input[pos] = (input[pos] >> key) | (input[pos]  << 8 - key);
        input[pos] = input[pos] ^ r1;
}
```

Comment: Use more parentheses in the expression `input[pos] = input[pos] << key | input[pos]  >> 8 - key;` (regardless of whether it is strictly necessary or not).

Comment: Use unsigned values when bit-shifting, otherwise you may get undesired or even undefined behavior.

Comment: @JonathanLefflercan you explain in more detail? I tried placing the expressions on either side of the OR in parentheses but I can't see much difference

Comment: Parentheses are for the benefit of the (human) reader.  The expression is a 'rotate left' operation, I believe.  But I think it would be easier to read if written as `input[pos] = (input[pos] << key) | (input[pos]  >> (8 - key));`.  I think that means the same as the unparenthesized version, but I'm sure that's correct without consulting the operator precedence chart.  Mixing arithmetic with bitwise operations is dodgy — make it clear.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler fair point, changes are in

Comment: In `char input[15] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO";` there is no space for the terminating `'\0'`. You cannot use string functions when the string is not correctly terminated.

Comment: @Bodo edited to use 16

Comment: The `printf(input)` lines are dubious.  You should be using at least `printf("%s\n", input)` to avoid any nastiness if something gets encrypted to a `%` symbol.  Are you sure nothing is ever encrypted to a zero byte?  If not, then you could appear to have truncated data.  Or you can use `puts(input)` (which adds a newline) or `fputs(input, stdout)` (which doesn't add a newline).  But all these will generate control characters in the output, and it isn't guaranteed to be valid UTF-8 in the output if your terminal works with UTF-8.

Comment: @3therk1ll You could omit the array size to let the compiler determine it from the initialization. You also have to either use `long input_len = sizeof(input) - 1;` or `long input_len = strlen(input);` to avoid losing the termination by encrypting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OR operation in `input[pos] << key | input[pos]  >> 8 - key` is not intended to OR overlapping bits, so it would not lose information. It is intended to perform a “rotate” operation, where the bits are rotated left by `key` positions, and the ones that are rotated out of the low eight bits by that are made to reappear coming “from the right.” That is what the `>> 8 - key` part does.

However, your `input` elements have a `char` type, which is likely signed. The encryption gives some of them negative values. Then, when decryption operators on `input[pos]`, the negative value is widened to an `int`, likely using two’s complement. This yields extra set bits above the eight bits it should operate on, so the data used in the operations is wrong.

One fix would be to change `char input[15] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO";` to `unsigned char input[15] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO";`.

Another would be to change `input[pos] = (input[pos] >> key) | (input[pos]  << 8 - key);` to:

```
unsigned char t = input[pos];
input[pos] = t >> key | t << (8 - key);
```

A similar change should be made in encryption, too. Either the use of non-ASCII characters or an `r1` with bit 7 set can result in negative values, in `input[pos]`, causing the same issue.

Comment: Absolutely bang on, thanks mate

Comment: I suggest to provide space for the terminating `'\0'` in `input` and make sure this character is not modified by the encryption or decryption: `char input[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO";` `long input_len = strlen(input);`